# How to upload file in server using springs

Tags: file, upload

I am new in springs and I want to upload the file in server. But it didn't save the file in that particular format..help me....

here is my jsp page.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Upload File Request Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br><br> 
    <!--     Name: <input type="text" name="file"><br> <br>        -->                 
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and controller file.

```
  public class FileUploadController 
  {
  private static final Logger logger =   LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileUploadController.class);

    /**
     * Upload single file using Spring Controller
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String upload(Locale locale, Model model)
    {
        logger.info("upload");
        return "upload";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, 
           @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) 
           {

             if (!file.isEmpty())
             {
               try 
               {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

                // Creating the directory to store file
                String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
                File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles/abc");
                  if (!dir.exists())
                     dir.mkdirs();

                // Create the file on server
                  File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name);
                BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();

                 logger.info("Server File Location=" + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

                return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name + "!";
               } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                  return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
                }
            } 
             else
             {
              return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
             }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

controller page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadFileHandler(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, 
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {


    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            System.out.println(">>>>"+ file.getOriginalFilename());
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            System.out.println(">"+rootPath);
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles/abc");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + file.getOriginalFilename());
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();

            logger.info("Server File Location=" + serverFile.getAbsolutePath());

            return "You successfully uploaded file=" + file.getOriginalFilename();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```